# How to combine icon + fill to export icon in sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I am new to sketch. I got handed a sketch document and trying to export icons included in the file.

This is what the folder looks like

[image]

You can see there are icons and Fills. On the sketch file it looks like any social media icon, but I cannot export them individually with the icon inside of the Fills (the fills are just a black cirlce).

Is there anyway I can combine the social media icons along w/ the Fills and export them together?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and export them as groups.

If you select the elements you want to export together by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting them in the layer list, and group them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, you can make that group exportable.

Select the newly created group and click on the bottom right side button "Make Exportable +" (as an alternative you can click on "Layer" > "Make exportable" in the menu). After that, you can set the desired file type and export the group.

Answer (score 0):

Group the fill and icon and then export them. Select the fill and icon by pressing down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to group them. After you have grouped them, you should be able to export them as a whole.